# django - simple way to re-use form to just display data?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I've created a form that has many fields. In another view, I need to display the data that was entered in the form. Is there a simple way to reuse the form, but this time to display the data that was entered (i.e. as 'readonly')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass your form and set all of the form widgets with the attribute `disabled`. Or set all of the fields to a widget that just renders text and no input box (like the django admin readonly widget).

```
class ReadOnlyForm(MyForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'true' # or replace the widget
            # with one that just returns the value in plain html

readonly_form = ReadOnlyForm(the_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to control how your form is rendered:

```
{% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label }}: {{ field.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks - I see how this could work, but I prefer Yuji Tomita's answer as it allows me to reuse my template.